# html adding up from a form and displaying a checkout total

Tags: javascript, html

ive done a form for multiple checkouts where a visitor to site clicks a radio button to select a product for printing...

i need to add;
a dropdown for selecting 1 or 2 sided print where selecting 2 sided adds £5 to the "amount" total
a dropdown for selecting artwork: customer supplies art, 1 side design or 2 sides where none is default, 1 side adds £10 to order, 2 side adds £15

then display a total preferably updates as radio and dropdowns selected rather than a recalculate button

how can you add dropdowns that recalculate a running total of the radio resulting amount and the two dropdown charges and display it???

can anyone help... im new to coding but had a real good go at this, code so far is;

```
    <FORM name = "orderform">
<input type="radio" name="amount1" value="99.99"> product 1 <br>
<input type="radio" name="amount1" value="129.00" checked> product 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="amount1" value="149.00"> product 3
<hr>
<input type="radio" name="amount1” value="199.00"> pack 1<br>
<input type="radio" name="amount1" value="229.00"> pack 2<br>
<input type="radio" name="amount1" value="249.00" checked> pack 3<br>

<input type="hidden" name="merchant_id" value="info@creaitve.co.uk"> <!-- nochex required -->
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="info@creaitve.co.uk">  <!-- paypal required -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP"> <!-- paypal required -->
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"> <!-- paypal required -->
<input name="instId" type="hidden" value="1243833" /> <!-- worldpay required -->
<input type="hidden" name="currency" value="GBP"> <!-- worldpay required -->

<input type="hidden" name="cartId" value="CreaITve"> <!-- worldpay cart name -->
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="CreaITve"> <!-- nochex cart name -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="CreaITve"> <!-- paypal cart name  -->

<input type="hidden" name="desc" value="Print Service A7 Leaflets"> <!-- worldpay product name -->
<input type="hidden" name="description" value="Print Service A7 Leaflets"> <!-- nochex product name -->
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Print Service A7 Leaflets"> <!-- paypal product name  -->

<SELECT name="printsides" onchange="a = this.options[selectedIndex].value; alert (a)">
<OPTION selected value="blank">Single Or Double Side Print</OPTION>
<OPTION value="0.00">Single Sided Print</OPTION>
<OPTION value="10.00">Double Sided Print</OPTION>
</SELECT>

<SELECT name="artwork" onchange="a = this.options[selectedIndex].value; alert (a)">
<OPTION selected value="blank">Choose an option</OPTION>
<OPTION value="0.00">I Will Supply Artwork</OPTION>
<OPTION value="10.00">1 Sided Artwork Design</OPTION>
<OPTION value="15.00">2 Sided Artwork Design</OPTION>
</SELECT>

var amount = amount1 + printsides + artwork



<!-- box here displaying the total preferable without having to click a recalculate button -->

<input type='submit' name='worldpay' value='WorldPay' formAction="https://secure.worldpay.com/wcc/purchase" method="POST"><autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return verifyfields()">
<input type='submit' name='nochex' value='NoChex' formAction="https://secure.nochex.com/"><autocomplete="off" onsubmit="return verifyfields()">
<input type='submit' name='paypal' value='Paypal' formAction="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
</FORM>
```

Comment: I think your mixing up javascript and java

Comment: edited, thanks dave am new to this :)

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: done, basically, how can i add up the value of the radio button with other charges from two dropdowns and display a total, from my old old programming days it used to be amount = radio + dropdown1 + dropdown2 but html sucks for calculations :(

Comment: Have you googled 'how to get value of input javascript' ?

Comment: Then did you additionally google 'math in javascript' ?

Comment: Or did you just expect us to write it all out for you

Comment: hi ProEvilz, not at all, ive edited the code above to the furthest i got inc the dropdowns, im new to java and very rusty on html too but ive tried the amount = amount1 + artwork + print etc but its showing on screen instead of calculating it been at this all day googling and trying allsorts of bits of code and cant get it to work for some reason :(

Answer (score 0):

Here is a decent prototype to get you going (you can merge it with your existing approach):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function calcTotal(form)
{
    var totalElem = null;
    var prodAmt = 0;
    var packAmt = 0;
    var printAmt = 0;
    var designAmt = 0;
    var totalAmt = 0;

    try
    {
        prodAmt=parseFloat(form["prodamount"].value,2);
        packAmt=parseFloat(form["packamount"].value,2);

        printAmt=parseFloat(form["printOpt"].value,2);
        designAmt=parseFloat(form["graphicOpt"].value,2);

        totalAmt = parseFloat(prodAmt+packAmt+printAmt+designAmt,2);

        totalElem=document.getElementById("Amount");
        totalElem.value = totalAmt.toString();
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        alert("calcTotal Error:  " + e.Message);
    }
    finally
    {

    }

}
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<form id="orderform" name = "orderform" onchange="calcTotal(this)">
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="99.99"> product 1 <br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="129.00" checked> product 2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="prodamount" value="149.00"> product 3
<hr/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="199.00"> pack 1<br/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="229.00"> pack 2<br/>
<input type="radio" name="packamount" value="249.00" checked> pack 3<br/>


<!-- need to add in here a dropdown for selecting single or double side print (single stays same price but selecting double side adds £5 to the "amount" variable -->
<select id="printOpt" name="printOpt">
<option value="0" selected>none</option>
<option value="0">single</option>
<option value="5">double</option>
</select>
<br/>
<!-- another dropdown to select graphic design either 1 or 2 sides - 1 side adds £10 to total, 2 side add £15 to total -->
<select id="graphicOpt" name="graphicOpt">
<option value="0" selected>none</option>
<option value="10">1 side</option>
<option value="15">2 side</option>
</select>
<br/>
<!-- box here displaying the total preferable without having to click a recalculate button -->
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
<input type="text" id="Amount" name="Amount" value="0"/>
<div id="totalAmt"></div>

</form>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    // Calculate the initial total
    calcTotal(document.getElementById("orderform"));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks v much codemaker its about 25 years since i programmed in pascal and cobol so am rusty and on 2+ decades catchup here lol....

Comment: ive posted an answer above as wouldnt let me include the code in here?? as it reads for some reason the Amount total isnt being recognised but if i inc a dropdown for "amount" field just to test it works... do you know why it wouldnt accept the Amount total as calculated in the javascript?

Comment: (1) <input type="radio" name="amount1" value="199.00"> pack 1<br> has what looks like a different character than an actual quote.  (2) You need to group radio inputs using the SAME name to associate them, therefore, UNLESS you want Product and Pack options to be in the same group, give them different names (see my sample above)...also, only ONE radio item can be "checked" in a group (3) I call the calcTotal function when there is a change in the form using <form id="orderform" name = "orderform" onchange="calcTotal(this)">

Comment: its the one below codemaker... down a bit lol.... ive merged your code with mine and just changed the 1 variable to Amount as thats the field name the gateways require.... when i run the code it adds up find but the gateway rejects,,, but if i add that selection box code near bottom for testing the "amount" field entry it works but not recognising the "amount" total in the javascript variable to pass over to the gateway, am i missing something? the "amount" variable has to hold the total balance from the form but not seeming to??